# Gamepad events not being triggered in IOKit on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, core-foundation, iokit

I've written some basic code based on the very few examples I could find online for reading gamepad events in IOKit and for me no events are ever fired and I'm not sure why. As is usual with coding on OS X, I'm sure I'm missing some obscure, undocumented function call or something to make everything work, but I don't know what it might be. My code is as follows:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <IOKit/hid/IOHIDLib.h>

@interface ViewController : NSViewController
{
    IOHIDManagerRef hidManager;
    int intHIDPage;
    CFStringRef strHIDPage;
    CFNumberRef numHIDPage;
    int intHIDUsage;
    CFStringRef strHIDUsage;
    CFNumberRef numHIDUsage;
    CFMutableDictionaryRef dctCriterion;
    IOReturn ioReturn;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

void OnGamepadConnect(void *context, IOReturn result, void *sender, IOHIDDeviceRef device) {
    NSLog(@"Gamepad connected.");
}

void OnGamepadDisconnect(void *context, IOReturn result, void *sender, IOHIDDeviceRef device) {
    NSLog(@"Gamepad disconnected.");
}

void OnGamepadEvent(void *context, IOReturn result, void *sender, IOHIDValueRef value) {
    IOHIDElementRef element = IOHIDValueGetElement(value);
    long elementValue = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue(value);
    NSLog(@"Gamepad event element=%@ value=%li", element, elementValue);
}

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    intHIDPage = kHIDPage_GenericDesktop;
    strHIDPage = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
    numHIDPage = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &intHIDPage);
    intHIDUsage = kHIDUsage_GD_GamePad;
    strHIDUsage = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
    numHIDUsage = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &intHIDUsage);
    dctCriterion = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFDictionarySetValue(dctCriterion, strHIDPage, numHIDPage);
    CFDictionarySetValue(dctCriterion, strHIDUsage, numHIDUsage);
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(hidManager, dctCriterion);
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(hidManager, OnGamepadConnect, nil);
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(hidManager, OnGamepadDisconnect, nil);
    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(hidManager, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    ioReturn = IOHIDManagerOpen(hidManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback(hidManager, OnGamepadEvent, nil);
    NSLog(@"Initialized! Return=%i RunLoop=%p", ioReturn, CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear {
    IOHIDManagerClose(hidManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    CFRelease(dctCriterion);
    CFRelease(numHIDUsage);
    CFRelease(strHIDUsage);
    CFRelease(numHIDPage);
    CFRelease(strHIDPage);
    CFRelease(hidManager);
    NSLog(@"Finished");
    [super viewWillDisappear];
}

-(void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
}

@end
```

Other than the code above, everything else in the project is default. The only thing that ever appears in the output is the "Initialized!" message at start and "Finished" message at exit despite me plugging/unplugging gamepads and mashing buttons. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first port of call would be inspecting the I/O registry. You can use `ioreg` (cli), but for interactive hotplugging I'd use either Apple's `IORegistryExplorer` (in the Hardware I/O Tools package from the developer downloads area), or the open source equivalent, IOJones. There, you'll see an automatically updated tree with all drivers and devices, and if you plug in your gamepad, some objects should turn up in green. First thing to check is if the gamepad even comes up as a HID device, second, if it reports as a gamepad. Post a screenshot and I might be able to help some more.

Comment: I downloaded a program called YsJoystickCalibrator and it registers my gamepads as such and is able to read input from them properly, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with drivers or the hardware. I'm also using a variety of gamepads of different kinds for testing and none of them are detected by my code but all are working in YsJoystickCalibrator. Sorry I forgot to mention this is in my OP. As far as ioreg, I'm not sure what I should be looking for amongst its lengthy output...

Comment: Yeah, ioreg isn't great for interactive use. Try IORegistryExplorer or IOJones, they will show you devices that have turned up after the application was loaded in green. You can also narrow it down by typing "IOHID" in the search field.